# Can @classmethod be substituted using @staticmethod and returning an instance of the class?

Tags: python, static-methods, class-method

I was reading [this tutorial](https://realpython.com/instance-class-and-static-methods-demystified/) on  `@classmethod` and `@staticmethod`, I am not sure why is necessary to use `@classmethod`. I can have the same result using `@staticmethod` and returning an instance of the class, following the example of the tutorial:

```
class Pizza:
    def __init__(self, ingredients):
        self.ingredients = ingredients

    @classmethod
    def prosciutto(cls):
        return cls(['mozzarella', 'tomatoes', 'ham'])

    @staticmethod
    def prosciutto2():
        return Pizza(['mozzarella', 'tomatoes', 'ham'])
```

I was wondering if there is any difference between this two implementations:

```
p = Pizza.prosciutto() 
p1 = Pizza.prosciutto2()
```

Can a static method that returns an instance of its own class be used instead of a class method without any disadvantage?

Comment: For example, when you subclass `Pizza` and want to return correct class, you need to use `@classmethod`

Comment: @AndrejKesely What do you mean for subclass?

Comment: `class MyPizza(Pizza):` When you use `@staticmethod`, you don't know if you were called from `Pizza` or from `MyPizza`

Comment: @AndrejKesely thanks formalize your comment as an aswer so I can upvote it

Comment: There's already answer from Blckknght. You can upvote his :)

Comment: @AndrejKesely: Great minds think alike!

Answer (score 3):

When there's only a single class, like in your example, then either a `classmethod` or a `staticmethod` (that names the class explicitly in its implementation) can work. But if you want to be able to extend the class in the future, you probably want to use `classmethod`.

Here's an example that builds on your code:

```
class ThinCrustPizza(Pizza):
   pass
```

If you call `ThinCrustPizza.prosciutto()`, you'll get an instance of `ThinCrustPizza`, not the base `Pizza` class it inherited the method from. That's because `cls` in the `classmethod` will be the class you called it on, which is the child class.

But if you call `ThinCrustPizza.proscutto2()`, you'll get the same `Pizza` instance you would get from calling it on `Pizza`, since the implementation needed to refer to `Pizza` by name. Because it doesn't get the class passed in, it can't tell that it was called on a subclass.